# How to form Elastic Search Request to return records using Group By

Tags: elasticsearch

My requirement is I need to form a request to get the count of All the Guests whose 'arrivalDt' is greater than the current date group by 'resId'. The data has resId, Guest Info, arrivalDt. There will multiple records with the same resrvationId(resId) with Individual Guest details for that reservation.

I have formed the below query that returns the count based on reservationId, but am unable to add the above date condition.

```
{
"size": 0,
   "aggs": {
    "group_by_reservation": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "resId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Filter Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) to add the condition.

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggregations": {
  "filteredLiveProducts": {
     "filter": {
        "range": {
           "arrivalDt": {
              "from": "now"        // should be a date field
           }
        }
     },
     "aggs": {
        "group_by_reservation": {
           "terms": {
              "field": "resId"
           }
        }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: The query is returning the data but the counts are not matching.. When I tried to cross check for one reservationId, Using the above query the count is 6 and when I individually queried using the reservation Id it returned 11 records and all the dates are greater than current date.

Comment: Can you share what documents are not being returned by above query. What is the format in which `arrivalDt` has been stored?

Comment: Actually I have added the size value as 10000000  and it worked.  "aggs": {
        "group_by_reservation": {
           "terms": {
              "field": "resId",                                                                                         
               "size": 10000000}
        }

Comment: Change this to `size : 0` if you want to retrieve all the buckets.